# Calculate Gesture Speed

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect.toolbox

Using the Kinect.Toolbox from codeplex, how can we get the speed of a swipe gesture

I was assuming using the following function from the SwipeGestureDetector class:

```
protected bool ScanPositions(Func<Vector3, Vector3, bool> heightFunction, Func<Vector3, Vector3, bool> directionFunction, 
        Func<Vector3, Vector3, bool> lengthFunction, int minTime, int maxTime)
    {
        int start = 0;

        for (int index = 1; index < Entries.Count - 1; index++)
        {
            if (!heightFunction(Entries[0].Position, Entries[index].Position) || !directionFunction(Entries[index].Position, Entries[index + 1].Position))
            {
                start = index;
            }

            if (lengthFunction(Entries[index].Position, Entries[start].Position))
            {
                double totalMilliseconds = (Entries[index].Time - Entries[start].Time).TotalMilliseconds;
                if (totalMilliseconds >= minTime && totalMilliseconds <= maxTime)
                {
                    return true;  
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

but cant think of a way how speed will be retrieved and calculated

Comment: Doesn't Distance = Rate * Time?  So couldn't you take the start position, the end position, the time it took to get from start to finish, apply a little math and get the Rate?

Comment: @sous2817 You would have to the distance between multiple points on the gesture then add them together otherwise it will be accurate, but yes

Comment: @sous2817 how would I get the rate, and would do you mean exactly by rate

Comment: @OutlawLemur how would I get distance between multiple points, by points do you mean Positions. Is there anything that represents distance directly in the code

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U2L3DP.html

@OutlawLemur: Sure, however you need to calculate the total distance and the total time is up to the situation.  The core formula shouldn't change too much.

Comment: so how would you get the total distance

Comment: you'd have to capture the start point and the stop point and calculate the distance (subtract start point from stop point will give you the number of units that the gesture traveled).  If there's a shift in the gesture, it still has a stop and then a start in a new direction. You'll have to capture each start and stop point calculate the distance between that start and stop combination and add the distance from each start and stop together once all of the gestures are complete.

Comment: @sous2817 Or use the distance formula (`sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 +(z2-z1)^2)`), and you can even get acceleration in m/s^2 because Kinect's depth uses meters

Comment: When the speed is created inside the second if statement, how can I pass it into another class or a method in the same class. Thanks